# Replace dictionary's value list with corresponding key-value mapping from another dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

I have these two dicationaries:

```
Dict_Employee_ID = {'0': ['0', '1', '2'], '1': ['0', '1', '2']}    

Dict_ID_Shift = {'0': ['L', 'D'], '1': ['D', 'E', 'D'], '2': ['None', 'Any', 'Any']}
```

My goal is to replace the value of the dictionary `Dict_Employee_ID` by the value of the dictionary `Dict_ID_Shift` when the keys of `Dict_ID_Shift` correspond to the value of `Dict_Employee_ID`

The expected output should look like this:

```
{
    '0': [['L', 'D'], ['D', 'E', 'D'], ['None', 'Any', 'Any']], 
    '1': [['L', 'D'], ['D', 'E', 'D'], ['None', 'Any', 'Any']]
}
```

I have tried using the intersection() method but couldn't get the expected results, what would be your strategy ? Thank you

Comment: Are you allowed to use additional libraries? About how many dict replacements are we talking? I am just thinking about using pandas' merge function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *dictionary comprehension* and reassign the value to `Dict_Employee_ID` as:

```
Dict_Employee_ID = {'0': ['0', '1', '2'], '1': ['0', '1', '2']}
Dict_ID_Shift = {'0': ['L', 'D'], '1': ['D', 'E', 'D'], '2': ['None', 'Any', 'Any']}

Dict_Employee_ID = {k: [Dict_ID_Shift[e] for e in v] for k, v in Dict_Employee_ID.items()}
```

where `Dict_Employee_ID` will hold the value:

```
{
    '0': [['L', 'D'], ['D', 'E', 'D'], ['None', 'Any', 'Any']],
    '1': [['L', 'D'], ['D', 'E', 'D'], ['None', 'Any', 'Any']]
}
```

---

If you want to replace in existing dict, then you can also write the explicit `for` loop to achieve this as:

```
for k, v in Dict_Employee_ID.items():
    Dict_Employee_ID[k] = [Dict_ID_Shift[e] for e in v]
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you want the value of a key in Dict_Employee_ID to be equal to when it is not found in Dict_ID_Shift, so I'm assuming you want it to preserve its old value. The below code should give you the result you're looking for:

```
Dict_ID_Shift_Values = list(Dict_ID_Shift.values())
for key in Dict_Employee_ID:
    if key in Dict_ID_Shift:
        Dict_Employee_ID[key] = Dict_ID_Shift_Values
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the values in the dictionary, and through each value, accordingly, using `dict.get` to check for membership:

```py
for sub_list in dict_employee_id.values():
    for i, val in enumerate(sub_list):
        # Second argument will keep the value the same if it isn't
        # in the dictionary
        sub_list[i] = dict_id_shift.get(val, val)
```